# Laravel Stats Tracker - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I am having issues installing the `"pragmarx/tracker"` package for Laravel 8.

For some reason, I am getting an error.

**Error:**

[image]

**Composer.json:**

[image]

Comment: what version of composer you're using?

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: @OMiShah Composer version 2.0.11 2021-02-24 14:57:23